# Trade-off between LDO max Iout AND PSRR

Tags: mosfet, analog, cmos, ldo

PSRR is inversely proportional to output impedance of LDO.

But Iout_max of LDO is proportional to width of output mosfet (M20) , Rds of M20 is inversely proportional to width of M20.

Given that output impedance is a parallel impedance configuration between Rds of M20 and (R1+R2), so Iout_max is proportional to output impedance of LDO.

If I need Iout_max = 3A, then my PSRR result looks very very bad. Any advice on [this LDO circuitry](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Eoru2_ghkTh_Pi5ZrWmAP08WHl2oM3P/view?usp=sharing) ?

[image: PSRR definition]

[image: PSRR negative feedback]

[image: LDO PSRR Result]

[image: LDO transient simulation circuit]

[image: LDO transient simulation result]

Comment: PSRR is mainly a function of the loop gain. The output device is part of this loop, but not the most significant part. The total output noise of the LDO will be affected partly by choice of the output device, as this must be suppressed by the loop gain, but that's noise, not PSRR.

Answer (score 0):

PSRR depends on the high-frequency gain of the regulator feedback loop.

If the power-dissipation device has lots of capacitance to charge and discharge, them the regulator loop needs HIGH operating current.

However, the LDO also needs suitable awareness of the risks of sloppy attention to IC LAYOUT.

Diagnosing an LDO with poor PSRR even at 60Hz, I eventually noticed the UNREG input metal was directly over the huge area of a high-value (10 Meg Ohm) feedback resistor.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by **PSRR depends on the high-frequency gain of the regulator feedback loop.** ?